# how to sum distinct by mutiple column

Tags: group-by, sum, distinct

I'm struggling to achieve this

```
VM  Disk    Capacity
VM1 Disk 1  100
VM1 Disk 2  40
VM1 Disk 1  100
VM1 Disk 2  40
VM2 Disk 1  45
VM2 Disk 1  45
VM3 Disk 1  30
VM3 Disk 2  30
```

The result should be like this

```
VM    Capacity
VM1    140
VM2    45
VM3    60
```

Comment: This is a simple question, but you need to show that you've attempted some sort of code. SO isn't a place for handouts.

Comment: @user3330821 Can you check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
SELECT a.column1, SUM(column3) FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, column3 FROM tableA
) a 
GROUP BY column1
```

Comment: Sorry @ydoow, I accidentally edited your answer.  Down vote for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/285fe

```
SELECT a.vm, SUM(capacity)
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT vm, DISK, capacity
FROM TEMP
) a
GROUP BY vm
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.vm, SUM(capacity) as capacity FROM
  (
SELECT DISTINCT vm, disk, capacity FROM test
  ) a 
GROUP BY vm
```

## [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a683f/4)

[image]